# How to retrieve the lastest file stored on local disk in UWP

Tags: uwp, storagefile

I am trying to retrieve the latest file that is stored in my picture library in my UWP application. I know how to retrieve the file by name... however, I would like the retrieve it by the date/time, which is the latest file.

How can I change the following codes?

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
string name = "Photo.jpg";
var manifestFile = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync(name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access `GetBasicPropertiesAsync` method for different properties

In your case, `DateModified`

```
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
StorageFile lastModifiedFile = null;
DateTimeOffset lastDate = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
foreach(var file in files) 
{
    var basicProperties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    var date = basicProperties.DateModified;
    if(date > lastDate) 
    {
      lastDate = date;
      lastModifiedFile = file;
    }
}
```

`lastModifiedFile` is one you need now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.... however, I am not very sure on how do loop on files. Is it possible for you to write a clearer answer? Thank you!

Comment: I am getting an error from "lastDate = date;" it says "Cannot implicitly convert type'System.DateTimeOffset' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Sorry I forgot, check now

Comment: I debugged, but an error appeared on the line you last modified, "The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000."

Comment: for "DateTimeOffset lastDate = DateTime.MinValue;"